# How to add custom modules to perl carton?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use carton as deployment container. But I ran into a small problem. I don't know, how to install private modules.

Created a quick test module:

```
h2xs -AX Foo::Bar

tree Foo-Bar/
Foo-Bar/
├── Changes
├── lib
│   └── Foo
│       └── Bar.pm
├── Makefile.PL
├── MANIFEST
├── README
└── t
    └── Foo-Bar.t
```

Packaged it: `tar cvfz Foo-Bar-0.01.tar.gz Foo-Bar/`
Copied the package to `vendor/cache` directory.

```
ls vendor/cache/
Foo-Bar-0.01.tar.gz  Try-Tiny-0.18.tar.gz

cat cpanfile
requires 'Foo::Bar', '0.01';
requires 'Try::Tiny', '0.18';

carton install --cached
Installing modules using /home/donpedro/Garbage/Carton/cpanfile
! Couldn't find module or a distribution Foo::Bar (0.01)
Successfully installed Try-Tiny-0.18
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Foo::Bar' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for /home/donpedro/Garbage/Carton/.
1 distribution installed
Installing modules failed
```

Tried a Milla default module also(tutorial example, milla new Dist-Name), but no results. Documentation mentions that for DarkPan modules, just drop the module into the vendor/cache directory, which I'm trying to do.
Official CPAN modules can be just dropped into the vendor/cache directory.

What to try next or how to solve my problem? :)

**Edit:**
miyagawa and lejeunerenard in the carton IRC channel gave me this information:
For this to work at the moment, one needs Carton 1.1 (current stable 1.0) and new cpanfile dev version. cpanfile has the new option 
`-dist => '/path/to/Foo-Bar.tar.gz' argument for the requires method`

As I'm too lazy to be early adopter, I will go with Carton for CPAN bundles and cpanm for private bundles.

Thanks miyagawa and lejeunerenard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

miyagawa and lejeunerenard in the carton IRC channel gave me this information: For this to work at the moment, one needs Carton 1.1 (current stable 1.0) and new cpanfile dev version. cpanfile has the new option -dist => '/path/to/Foo-Bar.tar.gz' argument for the requires method

As of now(28.12) there is still no Carton version bump and git 1.1 branch is 3 months old. So things take a bit time. Pinto seems to be under active development at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just put your modules in local/lib/custom (or whatever) and then use that lib in your perl app - or add it to PERL5LIB or use perl -Ilocal/lib/custom.